# Login error message validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to show the error message if user didn't enter username and password and try to click on login. I am trying to show error messages like username not entered and password not entered. But its not working perfectly.

Here is my controller:

```
public function login_user() {

    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean','required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean','required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $this->load->view('login_view');
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname')
        );
        $result = $this->login_database->login($data);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
                    // Add user data in session
            $this->session->set_userdata('username', $data['username']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('firstname', $data['firstname']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('lastname', $data['lastname']);

            //redirect to dashboard
            $this->load->view('include/sidenavbar');
            $this->load->view('include/topnavbar');
            $this->load->view('dashboard');
        } else {
            if($data['username']=='')
            {
               $this->session->set_flashdata('err_message', 'Username Not Entered !');
            }

            $this->session->set_flashdata('err_message', 'Login is invalid. Please try again !');
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my model:

```
public function login($data) {

    $condition = "username =" . "'" . $data['username'] . "' AND " . "password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'";
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php 
if( $this->session->flashdata('err_message') )
{
    echo $this->session->flashdata('err_message');
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me out how to resolve that?

Comment: actuallly i removed..i commneted in code..i didn't use that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the message by passing in array like below.

```
$this->load->library('session');

$this->session->set_flashdata('err_message', array('message' => 'Username Not Entered','class' => 'alert alert-warning'));
```

Thanks.

Comment: i am trying to show the error messages if username  and password field is empty

Comment: can you please help me out.how to fix that

Comment: Hi @Lavish Tyagi i have one more doubt can i ask?

Comment: i stored my user password in my db as hash..so when i try to login its not working..can you please help me how to use password_verify in my model function

Comment: simply encrypt the password with same method while storing that into database and then match the both entered and saved password.

Answer (score 1):

I tried like this then its working perfect.

View:

```
  <?php echo form_error('username','<span class="error">','</span>'); ?>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                     <?php echo form_error('password','<span class="error">','</span>'); ?>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

I used form_error to display the errors for each field.

then its working perfectly.